# A href wont resize

Tags: javascript, html, joomla, href

So i wrote a simple script that makes my div with thumbnails 100% width with having the right proportion of images.
It works perfectly on Firefox, but bugs out on other browsers. What could be the problem?

It works only when i click on the href links.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        $(window).load(function() { 
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                var ww = $(window).width();
                var th = $(".horislider_thumb").height();
                var tw = $(".horislider_thumb").width();

                ratio=tw/th;
                th=ww/ratio;
                tw=th*ratio;

                $(".horislider_thumb").css('max-width', tw + 'px');
                $(".horislider_thumb").css('max-height', th + 'px');
                $(".horislider-thumb-out").css('max-width', tw + 'px');
                $(".horislider-thumb-out").css('max-height', th + 'px');

            });
    });

        $(window).resize(function() {         
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                var ww = $(window).width();
                var th = $(".horislider_thumb").height();
                var tw = $(".horislider_thumb").width();

                ratio=tw/th;
                th=ww/ratio;
                tw=th*ratio;

                $(".horislider_thumb").css('max-width', tw + 'px');
                $(".horislider_thumb").css('max-height', th + 'px');
                $(".horislider-thumb-out").css('max-width', tw + 'px');
                $(".horislider-thumb-out").css('max-height', th + 'px');
                $('.horislider_thumb a').each(function(){
                    $(this).css('padding', '0');

                });

            });  

        });
    });
    </script>
```

This is the simple structure of my thumb's :

```
<div class="horislider_thumb" style="max-width: 1488px; max-height: 65.899px;">  
<a href="#0" style="padding: 0px;">
<img src="">
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Setting the image's width to 100% and its height to "auto" should respect its proportions already.

Comment: It has multiple href links so it makes img go for 100% width of the div not the href link